# Azure logic app HTTP request condition not working

Tags: azure, http, azure-logic-apps

I am designing a logic app that calls an API and according to the API's response moves forward.
But for some reason when the API call fails (i.e. it doesn't return 200 status code), the HTTP section of the logic app fails and does move forward at all.
For example:

[image]

In the above app if the URI returns anything besides 200 status code, the logic app fails and doesn't move forward.
But I want if the app doesn't return 200 status, it should still move forwards and check the condition and send an email.

[image]

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to adjust the  `Configure run after` settings for the `Condition 2` step ...

[image]

[image: Run After]